# Bourbon/Neat Rails Error: List index is 2 but list is only 1 item long for nth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, neat

Disclosure: This is my first Rails app

I'm getting an error within `Neat` when trying to use the `new-breakpoint` mixin. I have cut-up my application templates and am now spinning up and integrating them in to a new `Rails` instance. `Bourbon` and `Neat` work fantastically in my templates, but from within `Rails`, I'm getting...

`List index is 2 but list is only 1 item long for`nth'`

Has anyone come across this issue before?

More info can be found here [github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/issues/288).

The only thing I can think of is that there is an error in the `gem`? That doesn't make sense though as everyone would be experiencing the same issue. However, the only difference between using `Neat` in `Rails` comes down to using a `gem` and doing `@import "neat"` instead of `@import "neat/neat"` (from a folder)

If anyone can shed some light on whatever I can do to fix this, that would be fantastic.

Comment: I've been battling with this and just can't get it to work. From what I can tell, Bourbon / Neat just don't work in Rails? Seems unlikely, but it just doesn't seem to work.

For now, I've resolved to using Grunt to compile my sass and have bypassed that portion of Asset Pipeline. It works, but is a little messy. I would much rather have everything natively in Asset Pipeline